# The 3 vertical lines unicode fail to show on Firefox only

Tags: html

This HTML code shows the 3 horizontal lines "hamburger icon" fine on all the browsers but Firefox.
`<span id="mainMenuButton">&#9776;</span>`

here is the image taken from Chrome on MacBook.
[image]

How can I fix it so that it shows properly on all browsers? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an image or a font instead

font awesome for example:

http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/